# How to add a JPanel to a JFrame object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

Beginner programming student here. Trying to simply create JFrame object that allows me to click on the boundaries of the window and display the coordinates where I click. However, whenever I click a new location, the previous coordinates need to disappear. I have been told that one way to do this is by adding a JPanel to the center of the JFrame object. However when I do so I am getting an error that says that I am adding a window to a container. I may be extending something incorrectly from what I have read but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
public class Proj07 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Proj07Runner();
      }
    }

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Proj07Runner{
    
    GUI gui = new GUI();
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    int XCoor;
    int YCoor;
    
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("x = " + XCoor + ", y = " + YCoor, XCoor, YCoor);
    }
}

class GUI{
    public GUI(){
        MyFrame displayWindow = new MyFrame();
        displayWindow.setSize(300,100);
        displayWindow.setTitle("Insert name here");
        displayWindow.addWindowListener(new WProc1());
        
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        displayWindow.getContentPane().add(myPanel, "Center");
        displayWindow.setVisible(true);
        }
}

class MouseProc extends MouseAdapter{
    
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    ((MyFrame)e.getComponent()).XCoor = e.getX();
    ((MyFrame)e.getComponent()).YCoor = e.getY();
    
    e.getComponent().repaint();
    }
}

class WProc1 extends WindowAdapter{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I think the problem is where you put the listener:

You need to **do everything on the JPanel**, not the frame that is the container, so you should replace the declares with:

```
    MyFrame displayWindow = new MyFrame();
    displayWindow.setSize(300,100);
    displayWindow.setTitle("Insert name here");
    displayWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setSize(300,100);
    myPanel.addMouseListener(new myMouse)
    displayWindow.getContentPane().add(myPanel, "Center");
    displayWindow.setVisible(true);
```

And then **create a mouseListener** instead of a mouseAdapter to add in the JPanel.
Also **remove** the last WindowsAdapter thing, just use exitonclose.
**Edit:**
When it comes down to what the frame should do it should **only contain the panel**, so you also need to move everything you were doing on the frame to the panel (such as the `public void paint()` and stuff).
I would go as far as saying that if you want to add multiple panels on a frame, you should consider putting all panels **inside another panel** (as a container) and then putting that panel inside the frame.

Comment: I've made the adjustments but I am still getting the error that I cannot add a window to a container. I'm obviously missing something fundamental here but I am not sure what.

Comment: I got it to work! I deleted all of my previous class files and made it the only file in the folder and for some reason this caused it to compile and work. My only issue now is that the coordinates appear when I click but do not disappear when I click again. Not sure how to get this to work as I was only told that adding the panel could get this to work.

Comment: you need to call `repaint();`  for the Panel every time you want the graphics to change, or else all the previous stuff won't disappear because you are just painting on top. I would say the problem is about how you call the repaint. for example you should not paint on the frame (just an example since I cannot see your code).

Comment: So  (in case your code is still similiar to what you initially sent) it is not `displayWindow.repaint();` but `myPanel.repaint()`; . The frame should be doing nothing more than containing the panel, so the `public void paint(Graphics g)` stuff also needs to be put there

Comment: @Alex Brown Also please mark my answer as correct if it helped you solve your first issue :)

Comment: So I have added the listener to the panel instead and used the listener to call the repaint method on the panel and it is still not working correctly. Here is a snippet of my code regarding paint and repaint 
`class MyPanel extends JPanel{

 int XCoor;
 int YCoor;
 
 public void paint(Graphics g){
  g.drawString("" + XCoor + "," + YCoor, XCoor, YCoor);
 }
}`  `class MouseProc extends MouseAdapter{
 
 
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
 ((MyPanel)e.getComponent()).XCoor = e.getX();
 ((MyPanel)e.getComponent()).YCoor = e.getY();
 
 e.getComponent().repaint();
 }
}`

Comment: My apologies for the formatting, still new to this site

Comment: I have found the answer! When calling on `public void paint` I need to utilize the `super.paint(g)`  method in order to overwrite the previous repaint methods. I hope this can be useful to anyone else who runs across this problem!

Comment: That's nice to know! I had completely forgot about that...sorry.